# Setting custom center and zoom level for Zoom World icon in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2

OpenLayers Zoom Pan Control has a Zoom World Icon. When it is clicked the map zooms all the way out.

Is it possible to override this behavior and define a center and zoom level to which the map should be reset?

My Base Map is Bing Map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this without modifying the actual source code for openlayers (which you won't be doing if you're using a minified version, which by default you probably are), [look at this answer.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24684/8066)

However, I had to change it slightly for my code, which is using OpenLayers 2.11

```
OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom.prototype.buttonDown = function(evt) {
            var btn = evt.currentTarget ? evt.currentTarget : this;
            switch (btn.action) {
                case "panup": 
                    this.map.pan(0, -this.getSlideFactor("h"));
                    break;
                case "pandown": 
                    this.map.pan(0, this.getSlideFactor("h"));
                    break;
                case "panleft": 
                    this.map.pan(-this.getSlideFactor("w"), 0);
                    break;
                case "panright": 
                    this.map.pan(this.getSlideFactor("w"), 0);
                    break;
                case "zoomin": 
                    this.map.zoomIn(); 
                    break;
                case "zoomout": 
                    this.map.zoomOut(); 
                    break;
                case "zoomworld": 
                    alert("Hello world!");
                    break;
            }
        };
```

The only difference between this code and the one in the answer linked is that instead of `onButtonClick`, we're using `buttonDown`, and rather than `evt.buttonElement`, we're using  `evt.currentTarget`

**EDIT:** Internet Explorer has no `currentTarget` property in their event handling. Luckily, we can use `this` instead. I have modified the code above accordingly. For an explanation of this, please see [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) article. A relevant stackoverflow question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857439/internet-explorer-and-javascript-event-currenttarget).

Answer (score 1):

yes u can override this behavior with changing orginal code of openlayers...
in openlayers folders find **../lib/OpenLayers/Control/PanZoom.js**

then u must search "zoomworld" case in .js and then u cand change

```
this.map.zoomToMaxExtent()
```

to

```
this.map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x,y), zoomLevel)
```

May it be easy!